# How to create a keyword with an optional argument that defaults to None in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

How do I create a custom keyword in [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/) that takes an optional argument so that I can call that keyword either with or without argument? e.g. that argument should default to `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very basic example using built-in variable `${NONE}`:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Call Keyword Without Argument
    Log Name    

Call Keyword With Argument
    Log Name    Steve

*** Keywords ***
Log Name
    [Arguments]    ${name}=${NONE}
    Log    Your name is '${name}'
```

Note: Consider that according to Robot Framework documentation `${NONE}` and `${NULL}` are synonyms

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#boolean-and-none-null-variables

Answer (score 7):

Use `${arg_name}=${None}`

#### Example:

```py
*** Settings ***
Library    REST

*** Keyword ***
POST /endpoint
    # [Arguments]         ${body}=NONE              # BAD IDEA
    [Arguments]         ${body}=${None}             # BETTER
    &{response}=        REST.POST    /endpoint    ${body}
```

Now in your test cases you can call `POST /endpoint` w/ or w/o argument

```
POST /endpoint

# or

POST /endpoint    {"some": "valid json"}
```

#### Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
My Cool Test Case
    [Tags]              cool
    POST /endpoint
    POST /endpoint    {"Best Test Automation Framework": "Robot Framework"}
```

[image]

---

NOTE: don't use `NONE` since that will set the value to a string `'NONE'`